# Web Browser Control not registering a Navigated event

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, webbrowser-control

I am using navigation events in a web browser control I have placed on the second page of my application. It seems that the navigation events of forward and back are working correctly. However, I perform certain actions such as maintaining a current stack of browser urls that are used in my navigation events in my Navigated event handler, which does not always register when pages have been Navigated to depending on certain scenarios. The purpose of maintain a current stack of browser urls is to ensure that if the home page (which is the first page navigated to once the 2nd page of the application I loaded) is navigated to using the back stack, the application should return to the first page of the application as stated by Microsoft's requirements.

According to my debugging, I do not step through the Navigated event (shown below) if I use the following web browser control navigation scheme

MainPage > SecondPage with browser( Homepage > Forward > Forward > Back > Forward > Back (Navigated event does not occur) )

This seems confusing, but essentially once the browser has been navigated back (once or as many times as the user wants), and then forward navigation is resumed, the next time the user wishes to navigate to a previous page, that Navigated event never occurs even though the page is navigated back to.

To illustrate

```
//should always pass through this event when ANY navigation occurs
void TheWebBrowser_Navigated(object sender,
        System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        //If we are Navigating Backward and we Can Navigate back, 
        //remove the last uri from the stack.
        if (_IsNavigatingBackward == true && CanNavigateBack)
        {
            _NavigatingUrls.Pop();
        }


        //Else we are navigating forward so we need to add the uri 
        //to the stack.
        else
        {
            _NavigatingUrls.Push(e.Uri);

            //If we do not have the navigated uri in our history 
            //we add it.
            if (!_History.Contains(e.Uri.ToString()))
                _History.Add(e.Uri.ToString());
        }

        //If there is one address left you can't go back.
        if (_NavigatingUrls.Count > 1)
            CanNavigateBack = true;
        else
            CanNavigateBack = false;

        //Finally we hide the progress bar.
        ShowProgress = false;

        _IsNavigatingBackward = false;  //to eliminate staying as true when navigating forward and forward btn not pressed
    }

public void NavigateForward()
    {
        _IsNavigatingBackward = false;
        TheWebBrowser.InvokeScript("eval", "history.go(1)");

        //_IsNavigating = true;
    }

public void NavigateBack()
    {
        _IsNavigatingBackward = true;
        TheWebBrowser.InvokeScript("eval", "history.go(-1)");
    }

protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (CanNavigateBack)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            NavigateBack();
        }
        else
            base.OnBackKeyPress(e);            
    }
```

This issue with the Navigated event not occurring throws off the count of NavigatingUrls, and therefore the CanNavigateBack flag remains true on the home page (when the user is attempting to navigate through the back stack to MainPage again) when it should in fact be false, and the MainPage of my application can never be navigated to.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code (without the NavigateForward method) and its working fine. Am not sure how you are using that method.

Based on my observation, there may be something wrong with your NavigateForward method usage. How are you calling it and when are you calling it ??

Comment: Hmm. The only time I call navigate forward is on an app bar click event. I will upload a complete solution later today to my skydrive if you'd be willing to take a look.